# Android Management not working but it enrolls the devices

Tags: android-management-api

I'm trying to develop an internal EMM console, at first it seemed like everything worked fine but after further inspection we noticed that the enrolled device(via QR code) was not downloading the apps specified on the policy and when you call the list function we get {} instead of the device we just enrolled, I even went back to the [quick start guide](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/android-management-api-samples/blob/master/notebooks/quickstart.ipynb?authuser=2) but it's only failing. Is there anything we're missing?? the device is running 8.1.0

Comment: From my experience it may take up to 2 hours for apps to be installed on 8.1.0 devices. I've posted this issue several times to Google's EMM support, but without any definitive answer. So what happens if you wait a couple of hours?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the device failed to provision and the policy never reached the device, which results in the apps not being installed. You can check if the device is provisioned if there is a “Device Policy” section under Settings > Google.

Another way to check is by using [Devices.list()](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/list). If it is enrolled, Devices.list() also returns [nonComplianceDetails](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices#noncompliancedetail) which provides details why the app is not installed. For example, if the app is not installed due to an application not being available in your country. The return value of Devices.list() or Devices.get() will contain something like this:

```
 'nonComplianceDetails': [{'installationFailureReason': 'NOT_AVAILABLE_IN_COUNTRY',
   'nonComplianceReason': 'APP_NOT_INSTALLED',
   'packageName': 'com.sample.app',
   'settingName': 'applications'}],
```

Also, it might be helpful if you can tell what is exactly failing in the quickstart guide and what policy you are setting.

Comment: Thanks this helped me to track down why my device was not getting enrolled. I am also getting the error 'NOT_AVAILABLE_IN_COUNTRY' with a policy that is trying to install a kiosk app that is limited to a single country. 

Have you found a possible solution for this?